# "parsing" a text document to specific javascript format?

Tags: javascript, text-parsing

Edit - I think parsing it the wrong word to use, I'm actually looking to format that text file into the format I provided.

I'm working on a project and I've ran into a slight problem. I need help with mass editing a text file into a certain format. I don't really know how to do this. For example, here is the text file: http://frankerfacez.com/users.txt

That has the list of users and emotes (users without periods, emotes with). I would need that to be changed into the format of

```
//user
"emote":["cdn.frankerfacez.com/channel/ user / emote.png"],
```

For reference, this is what I need the format to be: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23313911/CustomEmotes.js

I really don't know how easy this will be or if it is even possible, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");


            var user = null;
            var emote = null;
            var o = {};

            for (i in lines) {
                var line = lines[i];
                if (line.charAt(0) != ".")
                    user = line;
                else {
                    try{
                        emote = line.substring(1, line.legth);
                        var a = new Array();
                        eval("var cnd = new String('cdn.frankerfacez.com/channel/'+user+'/'+emote+'.png');");
                        a.push(cnd.toString());
                        eval("o."+emote+" = a;");
                    }catch(e){
                        console.error(emote + " - " + user);
                        console.error(e);
                    }
                }

            }
            console.log(o);
```

Comment: I think parsing it the wrong word to use, I'm actually looking to format that text file into the format I provided. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @GamingTom maybe it's what u want. Consider my edit.